# Show image with onload

Tags: javascript

Need help to show `"default"` picture in the imageHolder when pages is loaded in JavaScript and replaced whit picture from the button click.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function changeImg(image) {
    var imghol = document.getElementById("imageHolder");
    imghol.src = image;
  }
</script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-s-4 col-m-12 col-l-12 col-xl-12">
    <p>
      <onload="changeImg('0.jpg')">
    </p>
    <p id="imageHolder" "changeImg('/upload_dir/pics/Beo/BeoLab/3/BLa3-Black.jpg')"></p>
    <p style="text-align: center; font-size:6px;"><a class="button" onclick="changeImg('1.jpg')" style="background-color: #000;" title="sort">&middot;</a>
    </p>
    <p style="text-align: center; font-size:6px;"><a class="button" onclick="changeImg('2.jpg')" style="background-color: #d2d2d2;" title="sort">&middot;</a>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-s-4 col-m-12 col-l-12 col-xl-12">
    <div class="panel" id="pic" style=" background-color:#fff;">
      <img id="imageHolder" / class="responsive">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please learn HTML properly before coding. `<onload="changeImg('0.jpg')">` is totally invalid.

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply!